# Displaying content from plugins in one placeholder tag

Tags: django, django-cms

I've recently installed the 'django-cms' extension and really like it so far, however i'm a little stuck on something. I've started adding placeholder tags to the template. But i want to be able to pull out content from within the placeholder tag rather than having a huge list of placeholder fields in the CMS.

So for example, on the homepage. I have 4 blocks. All with different images, and each image will display some text when you rollover with the mouse. So i've created my first placeholder tag - `{% placeholder "Block top left" %}` with within this placeholder tag, i've created a Text plugin and an image plugin.

Now i'd like to be able to pull out the Image from that placeholder tag, aswell as the text. So something like:

```
{% placeholder "Image top left" request.current_page.placeholder.image %}
{% placeholder "Image top left" request.current_page.placeholder.text %}
```

I know that's not correct but wondering if it was possible. I can't find anything in the docs. This is the only thing i can find - http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.3/advanced/templatetags.html#page-attribute but only limits you to the page title, slug etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to pull out information from the plugins within the placeholder?

Comment: The contents of the placeholder tag get rendered when your view is executed...I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: As it saves creating LOADS of different placeholders on the page, so when you go into to add content, there isn't a seperate section for each bit of text and image.

Comment: I can understand that, however, those of us with a lot of Django CMS experience have no idea what "Now i'd like to be able to pull out the Image from that placeholder tag, aswell as the text" means.

Comment: Apologies if it doesn't make sense, but you say you have a placeholder tag called 'body copy' Then in this body copy you add a text plugin and a image plugin. How do you control where they sit on the page? Because they are sat within one placeholder tag?

Comment: The plugins are rendered where the placeholder tag resides in the markup.

Comment: Yeah i know that, but say if you have 5 text boxes in one placeholder tag. Can you output them to different places on the template? Or will they just sit under one another, in the same placeholder tag?

Comment: Plugins within a placeholder are rendered in the order they appear in the placeholder in Django admin. If you need the content in a different place in the page, it needs to go into another placeholder, or have markup within the plugin itself that affects the layout.

Comment: Ok thanks, i've just seen a lot of people use multiple fields within a placeholder and thought there could be a way to do it to keep the page tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't do what I wanted. If you want the content to display in different parts of the HTML you need to use multiple placeholder tags. The plugins will appear after one another, within the same placeholder.